# TensorFlow: test_session and device placement

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm trying to use `tf.test.TestCase` and test specifically on both GPU and CPU. To this end, I'm using `self.test_session` and set `force_gpu` to either `True` or `False`. However, when running on a machine without a GPU, the behavior is different depending on whether `log_device_placement` is set to `True`.

```
with self.test_session(force_gpu=True) as sess:
    <add_ops>
    sess.run()
```

does not report an error, even if no GPU is present, while

```
with self.test_session(force_gpu=on_gpu,                                     
                       config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True)) as sess:
    <add_ops>
    sess.run()
```

does. Why is logging affecting the behavior?

Comment: Behavior for what to do without GPU is controlled by "soft_device_placement" option, I'm guessing when you specify the "config" option , it also affects that

Comment: `test_session` sets soft_device_placement according to force_gpu, so that should not be the cause (`config.allow_soft_placement = not force_gpu`)

Comment: quite possibly it's a bug in test_util.py, putting `print` in various places is a good way to ferret it out

Answer (score 0):

The relevant piece of code is here: 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/test_util.py#L385

It is not that enabling logging affects the behavior; it is an unintended side effect of *how* you are enabling logging.

To enable logging you provided a `tf.ConfigProto()` where all fields but `log_device_placement` have their default values. Boolean fields of protocol buffers default to `False` if you do not give them a value explicitly. In particular, `allow_soft_placement` defaults to `False`.

Normally, `tf.test_session()` sets `allow_soft_placement` to `True` if you do not set `force_gpu` to be `True`. However if you provide your own `ConfigProto`, it will not override the value of `allow_soft_placement` (unless you set `force_gpu` to `True`).

(Arguably the `test_session()` API could be improved, but that's probably a discussion better had on a GitHub issue.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the investigation. The weird thing is that as described in the question, the problem occurred even after setting force-gpu to True.